# Using Docker Secrets with Spotify Docker Client

Tags: java, spotify-docker-client

I'm using Spotify's Docker-Client, but have ran into a documentation wall.  I'm trying to figure out how to pass docker secrets that are already created in the environment to the containers built using docker-client.  The documentation only shows how to create secrets, but this isn't very useful since the secrets already exist.  I'm able to get a list of secrets in the environment using the `listSecrets` in `DockerClient`, but I have no way to convert them from `Secret` to `SecretBind`.  Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out looking through all of the code `spotify/docker-client` code.  The documentation does not show a way to convert a `Secret` to `SecretBind` that `ContainerSpec` needs to pass in the Docker Secrets.

```
public SecretBind createBind(Secret secret) {
    SecretFile file = SecretFile.builder()
                                .name(secret.secretSpect().name())
                                .uid("0")
                                .gid("0")
                                .build();
    SecretBind bind = SecretBind.builder()
                                .secretName(secret.secretSpec().name())
                                .secretId(secret.id())
                                .file(file)
                                .build();
    return bind;
}
```